# Sharepoint: form not validated after changing redirection

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I found a sutiblae way how to change the redirection behavior of my Sharepoint site. Unfortunatly now the form is not validated anymore and I can post empty forms.

How to validate the form before sent it to the server?

This Code changes the redirection:

```
 // for Save button
var button = $('input[accesskey="O"]'); 
button.removeAttr("onclick"); 

button.click(function() { 
    var customer = $("input[id^=Title][type=text]").val();
    var elementName = $(this).attr("name"); 
    var aspForm = $("form[id=aspnetForm]"); 
    var oldPostbackUrl = aspForm.get(0).action; 
    var currentSourceValue = GetUrlKeyValue("Source", true, oldPostbackUrl); 
    var newPostbackUrl = oldPostbackUrl.replace(currentSourceValue, "https://XXX/NewForm.aspx?customer="+customer);

    if (!PreSaveItem()) return false; 

    WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(elementName, "", true, "", newPostbackUrl, false, true));

});
```

Comment: what you want to achieve

Comment: As mentioned above I would like to: 
1. forward the User to the next form after submit
2. valid the form before submit

Comment: Maybe my problem is not clear. With this script I scip the standard validation from sharepoint and I'm able to post empty fields even if they are marked as required. Without modifying the button the validation is working fine.